# Split single column to multiple columns in KDB

Tags: kdb

I want to split values in a column to multiple columns after applying a complex function.

e.g. For the following trade table t , I want to split the sym into 2 separate columns sym and src. However, the function I would be applying would be slightly complex.

```
q)t:([] time:10:01:01 10:01:03 10:01:04;sym:`goog.l`vod.l`apple.o;qty:100 200 150)
time     sym     qty
--------------------
10:01:01 goog.l  100
10:01:03 vod.l   200
10:01:04 apple.o 150
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your table is very big and the sym column is very repetitive (which it looks like it will be if it's tick data) then the following will be much quicker:

```
f:{` vs'x}
@[t;`col1`col2;:;flip .Q.fu[f]t`sym]
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the way to get this done is :

```
q)update sym:sym[;0] , mkt:sym[;1] from update ` vs/:sym from t
time     sym   qty mkt
----------------------
10:01:01 goog  100 l  
10:01:03 vod   200 l  
10:01:04 apple 150 o
```

If you are not intrested in any other columns except the one  from the table that needs spliting then

```
q)exec  {`s`mkt!` vs x}each sym  from t
s     mkt
---------
goog  l  
vod   l  
apple o
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a table of `sym` and `src` by splitting on `.`, creating a dictionary then using `flip` to create a table:

```
q)show r:exec flip`sym`src!flip` vs/:sym from t
sym   src
---------
goog  l
vod   l
apple o
```

This can be joined to the original table using [each-both `,'`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/adverbs/#each-both):

```
q)t,'r
time     sym   qty src
----------------------
10:01:01 goog  100 l
10:01:03 vod   200 l
10:01:04 apple 150 o
```

If column order is important then this can be fixed with [`xcols`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dictsandtables/#xcols):

```
q)`time`sym`src xcols t,'r
time     sym   src qty
----------------------
10:01:01 goog  l   100
10:01:03 vod   l   200
10:01:04 apple o   150
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be;

```
q)(,'/)(t;flip`sym`src!exec flip ` vs'sym from t)
time     sym   qty src
----------------------
10:01:01 goog  100 l
10:01:03 vod   200 l
10:01:04 apple 150 o
```

Comment: Apologies, this is more or less the same as Thomas' answer